# Ответ от сервера

Tags: delphi, сервер, сокет

Реализую сервер на delphi. Возник вопрос. Отправляю ответ от сервера в таком виде:

```
ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[0].SendText('hello ');
```

Можно ли сделать, чтобы он сам определял какой пользователь без индекса 0?

Comment: А в каком событии вы это пишете?

Comment: Попробуйте компоненты TIDTCPServer TIdHTTPServer сервер. Или аналогичные из synapse. Так есть событие, когда клиент соединяется - создается отдельный поток с сокетом.

Comment: в событии: ServerSocket1ClientRead